# JQuery skipping the .on assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a piece of code that filters cards through a text input. But, I have been having trouble with the `.on` method. Below is the code that will accomplish this task.

```
$('.news-card').show(); //Reset everything
console.log("Started"); //This prints

$('#searchbar-sidebar').on('input', function () {
   txt = $('#searchbar-sidebar').val(); //Gets text
   console.log(txt); //This does not print
   $('.news-card').each(function () {
     if (txt === "") {
        $('.news-card').show(); //If there is nothing, show all
     } else {
        if ($(this).data("title").toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
          $(this).show(); //If it matches, then show
        } else {
            $(this).hide(); //If it does not match, hide!
        }
        console.log("3"); //This also does not print
     }
     console.log("2"); //This doesnt print
   });
   console.log("1"); //This doesnt also
 });
 console.log("0"); //This prints
```

So I did a couple of tests. If I were to paste this code in the console and run it, everything works fine. It was originally in a `.js` file. But then I moved it to the bottom of the `body` with a `<script>` tag.

So now things I would like to know,

- How do I stop this from happening again?
- How do I fix it for this scenario?

**EDIT:**
I added the HTML below:

```html
<body>
    <div id="side-div" class="sidebar">
        <h1 class="boxed-textbox" id="sidebar-logo">The Otto & Finch Press</h1>
        <input id="searchbar-sidebar" type="text" placeholder="Search for an article..." value="">


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.news-card').show(); //Reset everything
            console.log("Started"); //This prints

            $('#searchbar-sidebar').on('input', function (e) {
                var txt = $('#searchbar-sidebar').val(); //Gets text
                console.log("text", txt); //This does not print
                $('.news-card').each(function () {
                    if (txt === "") {
                        $('.news-card').show(); //If there is nothing, show all
                    } else {
                        if ($(this).data("title").toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
                            $(this).show(); //If it matches, then show
                        } else {
                            $(this).hide(); //If it does not match, hide!
                        }
                        console.log("3"); //This also does not print
                    }
                    console.log("2"); //This doesnt print
                });
                console.log("1"); //This doesnt also
            });
            console.log("0"); //This prints
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: How do you stop what from happening? You haven't said what the result is, other than it doesn't work

Comment: Why does this question deserve an up vote?

Comment: @ScottMarcus because it's a new user who posted the relevant code, described the situation and explained what they had previously tried. How else are they going to move up on the site if not with upvotes for doing things right?

Comment: @KScandrett Sorry if I did not elaborate as much as you wanted. In the code, I did specify which did not print. But now that you have brought that to light, nothing prints except Started and 0. And if I were to run it in console, it would work.

Comment: You should post a simplified version of your html and code so people can see how they interact.  Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evgWdm

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin That's not why a question should be upvoted. A question should be up voted when, not only is it formulated correctly, but it is complete in its explanations (this question doesn't post the relevant HTML and can't be reproduced) and is clear as to what the problem(s) are (several answers were posted that were not correct because they misunderstood what the OP was saying). Also, the question should not have been asked before.

Comment: You do have JQuery referenced prior to this code being encountered, right?

Comment: **How do I stop this from happening again?** What does that mean? What's happening that should only happen one time, not again?

Comment: OK. Just a helpful tip for the future - the result you're getting is best clearly stated in the question itself. Most people won't read through your code in detail until they understand the problem you're having. You'll also get better quality answers that way.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's Development Console?

Comment: Nope, none @KScandrett

Comment: Is the `searchbar-sidebar` element created dynamically? It sounds like it doesn't exist at the time the code runs

Comment: @KScandrett Nope. Its pure HTML.

Comment: Change `console.log(txt);` to `console.log('input value:', txt)`. It may be that it prints but prints a blank.  At least that will see if that line is reached

Comment: @KScandrett The line is never reached :(

Comment: Could you edit your answer and include relevant sections of the html please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the js code in this:

```
$(function(){
  //your code here.
});
```

Basically when jquery senses that the page has loaded fully it'll run your code. Otherwise your selectors might not be loaded yet.

This is all assuming your code works.

**EDITED stack snippet with updated html from OP**
This all seems to work. Not sure where the issue is OP.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-card" data-title="123">
  I am a fancy news card number 1 (search 123)
</div>

<div class="news-card" data-title="321">
  I am a fancy news card number 2 (search 321)
</div>

<div class="news-card" data-title="foo">
  I am a fancy news card number 3 (search foo)
</div>

<body>
  <div id="side-div" class="sidebar">
    <h1 class="boxed-textbox" id="sidebar-logo">The Otto & Finch Press</h1>
    <input id="searchbar-sidebar" type="text" placeholder="Search for an article..." value="">
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.news-card').show(); //Reset everything
      console.log("Started"); //This prints

      $('#searchbar-sidebar').on('input', function(e) {
        var txt = $('#searchbar-sidebar').val(); //Gets text
        console.log("text", txt); //This does not print
        $('.news-card').each(function() {
          if (txt === "") {
            $('.news-card').show(); //If there is nothing, show all
          } else {
            if ($(this).data("title").toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
              $(this).show(); //If it matches, then show
            } else {
              $(this).hide(); //If it does not match, hide!
            }
            console.log("3"); //This also does not print
          }
          console.log("2"); //This doesnt print
        });
        console.log("1"); //This doesnt also
      });
      console.log("0"); //This prints
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: or always better `jQuery(function( $ )) {`

Comment: `that the page has loaded fully` is a wrong statement for what your suggestion does. Can you improve on that one?

Comment: Still does not work. Although, `console.log("0");` did print this time. Thats a start!

Comment: @FaroukCharkas `0` is printed also in your version.

Comment: *"that the page has loaded fully"* Not really. A function passed to the JQuery object will be executed with the document is "ready". This correlates to the point in time when the DOM is fully parsed and loaded into memory. That is earlier than when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I realized while responding to a previous comment. Whoops.

Comment: The question says the problem happens when he puts the `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>`. At that point the DOM should be fully loaded, so it shouldn't be necessary to use the `document.ready()` method.

Comment: It printed `1`. I would assume that this means that the assignment has been completed but the actual mechanism does not work, yet all the code checks out.

Comment: @FaroukCharkas I added some code that seems to work. Without the wrap the code would not run. Without it it seems that Jquery is not ready at the point your code runs. The wrap waits for jquery to be ready.

Comment: @matt It still does not work. It just prints `0` and `Started`. I really appreciate that you made a working snippet. Maybe there is a JQuery property that we do not know about?

Comment: can you console log $('#searchbar-sidebar'). Does it exist? Seems like it could be an issue with your html. If so, could you maybe show us what your html is? Add it in your original question. :)

Comment: @FaroukCharkas I added your html to my answer. Seems to still function as you want. :S

Comment: Yea, for some reason it does not work. I really, really appreciate your time and effort, I will go ahead and accept your answer for your effort. @matt

Comment: @FaroukCharkas Appriciate it man. Sorry I wasn't able to get a final solution for you. Goodluck!